# The usage of radix sort

Tags: python, radix-sort

Let's say i have a file containing data on users and their favourite movies.

```
Ace: FANTASTIC FOUR, IRONMAN
Jane: EXOTIC WILDLIFE, TRANSFORMERS, NARNIA
Jack: IRONMAN, FANTASTIC FOUR
```

and based of that, the program I'm about to write returns me the name of the users that likes the same movies.

Since Ace and Jack likes the same movie, they will be partners hence the program would output:

```
Movies: FANTASTIC FOUR, IRONMAN
Partners: Ace, Jack
```

Jane would be exempted since she doesn't have anyone who shares the same interest in movies as her.

The problem I'm having now is figuring out on how Radix Sort would help me achieve this as I've been thinking whole day long. I don't have much knowledge on radix sort but i know that it compares elements one by one but I'm terribly confused in cases such as FANTASTIC FOUR being arranged first in Ace's data and second in Jack's data.

Would anyone kindly explain some algorithms that i could understand to achieve the output?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us how you sort your lists ? The quick and dirty code below give me the same output for sorted Ace and Jack.

```
Ace = ["FANTASTIC FOUR", "IRONMAN"]
Jane =  ["EXOTIC WILDLIFE", "TRANSFORMERS", "NARNIA"]
Jack = ["IRONMAN", "FANTASTIC FOUR"]

sorted_Ace = sorted(Ace)
print (sorted_Ace)

sorted_Jack = sorted(Jack)
print (sorted_Jack)
```

You could start comparing elements one by one from here.

I made you a quick solution, it can show you how you can proceed as it's not optimized at all and not generalized.

```
Ace = ["FANTASTIC FOUR", "IRONMAN"]
Jane =  ["EXOTIC WILDLIFE", "TRANSFORMERS", "NARNIA"]
Jack = ["IRONMAN", "FANTASTIC FOUR"]
Movies = []
Partners = []

sorted_Ace = sorted(Ace)
sorted_Jane = sorted(Jane)
sorted_Jack = sorted(Jack)


for i in range(len(sorted_Ace)):
    if sorted_Ace[i] == sorted_Jack[i]:
        Movies.append(sorted_Ace[i])
if len(Movies) == len(sorted_Ace):
    Partners.append("Ace")
    Partners.append("Jack")

print(Movies)
print(Partners)
```